# Retrieve Laravel 4.2 messagebag via ajax

Tags: php, laravel

I want to be able to retrieve laravel messagebag contents such as validation errors or other messages I place there on my form page BUT via ajax.

I currently return the errors to a `View` using `withErrors` and am comfortable with that approach. I want now for pop ups and other alerts to appear on the page using using jquery.

I've created an ajax call to a php script that attempts to retrieve the error messages but I can't get this simple bit to work.

So:

Assume I have set a message as follows:

```
$message = new Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
        $message->add( 'error', "Reservation Not Found. Error has been reported" );
```

I then want to retrieve that message later with:

```
Route::get('fetcherrors', function() {

    $errors = Session::get('errors');

    return Response::json($errors);

});
```

At the moment this does not work and returns an empty object.

1. How can I retrieve the content of the current `messagebag` from within a php script?
2. When does this `messagebag` expire? What triggers it to expire?

Confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MessageBag is just a fancy key/value storage. To retrieve a message from there, you can use `$messageBag->get('error')`.

To use this MessageBag somewhere else, you need to save it - in a Session for example. 
However, it might be easier to simply store an errors array and forget MessageBags. If you only need to validate some user input and save the error messages so you can retrieve them later, this is the approach I'd recommend. Sample code:

```
// Validation result
$errors = ['An error', 'Another error'];
Session::put('errors', $errors);

// Get error messages
$errors = Session::get('errors');
return Response::Json($errors);
```

If you have more messages you're trying to save and you insist on using MessageBags and want to do it the elegant way, here's an article that explains it: http://toddish.co.uk/blog/global-site-messages-in-laravel-4/

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense and the approach I will follow. I'll read the article as well. THanks